# Cant receive packets with UDP and SFML

Tags: c++, udp, sfml

I am having problems trying to get UDP to work with SFML in C++.

I have made a client class and a server class.
The server can send text messages and the client can receive and print them.
Server and client runs in the seperate threads.

The problem is, it is not working on LAN.
If I have the client and server running in seperate windows on the same computer I can send messages just fine, but if the server runs on one computer and the client on another on the same LAN, the messages aren't received.

I hope someone can help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you found the IP of the other computer? Did you added a firewall exception on the server computer?

Comment: I dont use an IP. I bind the client to a port and on the server I broadcast to that port. Shouldn't that work? I have added firewall exceptions.